# Getting shared distance of two parallel lines using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, distance, geometry

I have 2 lines Line A, and Line B that share from point. The 2 lines at first share the same path and are parallel, then they split into different paths. I would like to calculate that segment in which they are parallel. Picture below further explains visually. Red part is the wanted part.

[image: Example]

Note that the red segment might be multiple connected segments that make up the red path of each Polyline.
I doubt there is an interface in the arcobjects in which calculates this, which means I have to calculate it manually. I need some suggestions to get the best accurate result of the shared length.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [ITopologicalOperator interface](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#itopologicaloperator.htm), I can create a buffer for both line features, and then using the Intersects method which will return a geometry of the result of the intersection, which is the parallel section of the line. Then I can get it's length

Answer (score 2):

I would access `ITopologyExtension.MapTopology`, call `IMapTopology.AddClass` to  add your featureclass with a cluster tolerance a bit larger than the distance between the parallel lines.

Call `ITopologyGraph.Build`, then loop through each topology edge via `ITopologyGraph.Edges`, to populate a `List<IGeometry>` with geometries from `ITopologyEdge.Geometry` for edges where `ITopologyEdge.Parents` yields more than one parent.

I've also used a custom layer extension using `ILayerExtensionDraw` so that it simply draws the geometries (in red) for topology edges with more than one parent.

Answer (score 1):

Using ITopologicalOperator on the geometries themselves can return the desired geometry.  For instance the [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Intersect_Method/002m000003vs000000/) method has the option to choose the output geometry type.  Since you are interested in the polyline result, you can choose [esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriGeometryDimension_Constants/002m00000017000000/).  For instance:

```
IGeometry geom1 = (IGeometry)line1;
IGeometry geom2 = (IGeometry)line2;
ITopologicalOperator topOp = (ITopologicalOperator)geom1;

IGeometry results = topOp.Intersect(geom2, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension);
```

If the resulting geometry contains multiple geometries, you can cast the result to [IGeometryCollection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometryCollection_Interface/002m000001v1000000/), and iterate through the parts.

```
IGeometryCollection geomColl = (IGeometryCollection)results;
if (geomColl.GeometryCount > 0)
{
    for (int idx = 0; i < geomColl.GeometryCount; i++)
    {
        IPolyline resultLine = (IPolyline)geomColl.Geometry[idx];

        // do something with each resultLine
    }
}
```